# Must a question be explicit?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

I frequently see questions that are implicit: The question is not stated explicitly, but is probably obvious to most.  For example, some code and input is shown along with a stack trace.  The implicit question is, "how do I prevent this stack trace?"  These questions are sometimes voted for closure with the reason "unclear what you are asking", often with a comment along the lines of "what is your question?"

Example: [bson 4.0.0 gem error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705397/bson-4-0-0-gem-error)

Questions like this, which show a stack trace or error message, can be made explicit by adding the boilerplate "How do I prevent this problem?" to them.  That the exact same boilerplate will suffice for the vast majority of implicit questions seems to indicate that the missing explicit question does not represent much useful information.

Do we require all questions to be explicit, or is the existence of an implicit question *in itself* a reason to close a question?

Comment: Don't worry. Even if there is an explicit question, it doesn't mean that the explicit question is reasonably scoped, clear or useful.

Comment: I do wonder what that user searched for, when the exact text of the error they got is a question title that has the highest voted answer giving the exact solution they posted themselves.

Comment: If I could, I would vote to close it as dupe rather than unclear. In either case, it does seem like the users first reaction to an error message was to copy and paste it to stack overflow rather than, for example, reading it.

Comment: I'd take an explicit question over one where my assumption of what the implied question is turns out to be wrong and I get berated by the OP for failing to read their mind.

Comment: An explicit question implies at least *some* understanding of the problem. When I see somebody post a blob of code and a stack trace, I really doubt that they have done *any* debugging, or attempted to produce the *shortest* example that reproduces their problem. It also makes me doubt that they would understand any answers they happen to receive.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes... how should I improve the question?  Or is it that I didn't search SE first and find [the question this is probably a dup of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216780/158100)?

Comment: The down-votes probably just say: No, a question doesn't need to be explicit. I wouldn't lose sleep on it ....

Comment: Mostly, identify a canonical dupe and close as duplicate.  That's how NullReferenceException questions are handled.  They're all unique, but the solution is always the same, so the canonical can be used as a close target.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I think it is not unreasonable to expect a question to be explicit.

And your analysis that the boilerplate

> How do I prevent this problem?

could be the smallest edit needed to prevent non-constructive noise under the question.

My first action would be to edit the post to make the question explicit. I might leave a comment to make the OP aware of my reason for editing.

If there is no way to determine what the actual question is, just close vote as unclear. That will bring users to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

See also [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216780/158100) from [Richard Tingle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/220332/richard-tingle)

Do note that the specific question you linked to can not only use an edit to make the question explicit but also the title needs some love.

And with that I'm only left wondering how I make a perfect cappuccino ...